# Width or height for IE version

Tags: css, internet-explorer, responsive-design

Yo folks. Say, if I wanna set some fallback for height or width for IE version 9 and below, how should I exactly do this and in what order?

I know about the `\9` trick tho, but not sure how to use it. This way:

```
height: 100%;
max-height: 500px;
height: 500px\9;
```

or this:

```
height: 500px\9;
height: 100%;
max-height: 500px;
```

or perhaps this:

```
height: 100%;
height: 500px\9;
max-height: 500px;
```

Comment: first or third, second will be 100% height for all

Comment: ah, yeah... I see. `max-height` is also supported with IE8 and 9 as far as I can tell. So it would be ok to use the third variant, I guess. Thanks GCyrillus :)